# How to plot (almost) the same function at both sides of the "y" axis in R?

Tags: r, plot

I have a function that depends on distance and behaves different according to the direction (east or west) to where you evaluate it. Now I have two plots side by side, but I need to have them as one, where the labels of the axis are shared and the x axis label is centered. Here is an example of how the code looks right now:

```
x = (0:300)
par(mfrow=c(2,2))

Idriss70 = function(x){
exp(5.6315-0.4104*7-(2.9832-0.2339*7)*log(x+10)+0.00047*x+0.12)
}
plot(Idriss70(x), log = "x", type="l",xlim = c(300,1), xlab="Distancia [km]",ylab="PGA [g]", main="Aroma y Humayani extendida, Mw 7,0", col="green",   panel.first = grid(equilogs = TRUE))

Idriss70 = function(x){
ifelse (x >= 0 & x<=3, exp(5.6315-0.4104*7-(2.9832-0.2339*7)*log(0+10)+0.00047*0+0.12),
      exp(5.6315-0.4104*7-(2.9832-0.2339*7)*log(x+10)+0.00047*x+0.12))
}
plot(Idriss70(x), log = "x", type="l", xlab="Distancia [km]",ylab="PGA [g]", main="Aroma y Humayani extendida, Mw 7,0", col="green", panel.first = grid(equilogs = TRUE))
```

As you can see, the log scale of the plots don't allow "negative" values to be evaluated  so I haven't been able to use only one plot.

How can I get this plot as one without using Illustrator or another graphics software, as I have to create lots of this ones for differente areas?

I haven't used ggplot in the past but I am willing to learn if necessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can basically make one plot and mess around with `fig` so that you restrict the first plot to the left half of the device and the second to the right half

```
x <- 0:300

Idriss70 = function(x){
  exp(5.6315-0.4104*7-(2.9832-0.2339*7)*log(x+10)+0.00047*x+0.12)
}

Idriss71 = function(x){
  ifelse(x >= 0 & x<=3,
         exp(5.6315-0.4104*7-(2.9832-0.2339*7)*log(0+10)+0.00047*0+0.12),
         exp(5.6315-0.4104*7-(2.9832-0.2339*7)*log(x+10)+0.00047*x+0.12))
}

par(fig = c(0, .5, 0, 1), mar = c(5, 4, 4, 0), xaxs = 'i', ann = FALSE)
plot(Idriss70(x), log = "x", type="l", xlim = c(300,1),
     col="green", axes = FALSE, panel.first = grid(equilogs = TRUE))
xx <- axis(1)
axis(2)

par(fig = c(.5, 1, 0, 1), new = TRUE, mar = c(5, 0, 4, 2))
plot(Idriss71(x), log = "x", type="l", col="green",
     panel.first = grid(equilogs = TRUE), axes = FALSE)
axis(1, at = xx, labels = c('', xx[-1]))

title(xlab = "Distancia [km]", main = 'Aroma y Humayani extendida, Mw 7,0',
      ylab = 'PGA [g]', outer = TRUE, line = -1.5)
```

[image]

good luck with ggplot. you'd probably have to summon @baptiste

well you could still use `mfrow` I suppose

```
graphics.off()
par(mfrow = c(1, 2), mar = c(5, 4, 4, 0), xaxs = 'i', ann = FALSE)
plot(Idriss70(x), log = "x", type="l", xlim = c(300,1),
     col="green", axes = FALSE, panel.first = grid(equilogs = TRUE))
xx <- axis(1)
axis(2)

par(mar = c(5, 0, 4, 2))
plot(Idriss71(x), log = "x", type="l", col="green",
     panel.first = grid(equilogs = TRUE), axes = FALSE)
axis(1, at = xx, labels = c('', xx[-1]))

title(xlab = "Distancia [km]", main = 'Aroma y Humayani extendida, Mw 7,0',
      ylab = 'PGA [g]', outer = TRUE, line = -1.5)
```

Comment: @AlexA. i doubt hadley would approve of this x-axis

Comment: Thanks for this answer, it is exactly what I wanted to do, and it gave me some clues to resolve other problems I had.